# How to send automated email in node js 24hours before a fixed date?

Tags: node.js, email, schedule

I want to implement a setup in my node app where the server can send emails to a number of people 24hrs before a specific date. This date is coming from DB.

For example: The date is 25th December, so I need my server to send mails to a group of clients on 24th December. How do I code it today such that it will send the mail in future?

(My node app is hosted on a VPS so it will be running always.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the node-schedule modules. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2020, 12, 24, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(y){ });
```

Or you can do it the old fashioned way. Something like.

```
const then = "2020-12-24 05:00:00";

const inter = setInterval(() => {
    const now = new Date();
    if (Date.parse(now) > Date.parse(then)) {
       clearInterval(inter);
    }
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 );
```

**Edit:**

You could have something like.

```
const schedules = {};

function dbUpdate() {
    const somedate = new Date();
    const userid = getUpdatedUser();
    cancelSchedule(userid);
    createSchedule(userid, somedate);
}

function createSchedule(userid, somedate) {
    const date = new Date(somedate);
    schedules[userid] = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(y){ });
}

function cancelSchedule(userid) {
    schedules[userid].cancel();
}
```

Not tested but something along these line

Comment: I understood the base, but I had a doubt. What will happen if I start the server today and restart it in between? Will that affect the scheduled job in any way?

Also, in the 2nd approach, won't that if statement be satisfied every time after 24th december? I want the email to be sent only once and that case will send emails after every (1000*60*60) time after 24th of December.

Comment: No, the schedule will run everytime you restart the server. Yes, but you can use clearInterval when the statement is satisfied. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: Hi, I was having issues in node-scheduler. I need to run it for a list of users and that list might be changing/updating in the db. So, I put the scheduler into a setInterval of 1hr so that it takes updated data from the db but unfortunately, it is now stacking the jobs every hour but I need it to reschedule the job for users who already have the job set. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Don't put the schedule in an interval. It will do that for you. just run the needed code in the schedule

Comment: But once my scheduler has run the job for each user, what if the list updates in my db? The jobs are already assigned according to the old list of users. I want it to get the updated list from db and set jobs for the new users added without having to restart the server.

Comment: Think about the problem and how best to solve it. I dont know the full details of your project but you could cancel the schedule for a user and create a new one on db update. Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#jobcancelreschedule. Read the docs.